# What is it called when you refer to someone by using an adjective rather than their name?

Tags: adjectives, proper-nouns

For example; the "the brunette said" instead of "Susan said" or "The young man asked" rather than "Jason asked".

Comment: It's not much more than the very common practice of using descriptors in an  identifier role. 'Do you see those books? Could you pass me the large red one / 'The Lord of the Rings'?

Answer (score 2):

This is an [epithet](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/epithet)

> an adjective added to a person's name or a phrase used instead of it, usually to criticize or praise them:

Comment: "Young man" doesn't sound like much of an epithet, though.